# Reformat contigency table in R

Tags: r

Given I have a contigency table formatted in a object like so:

```
   Democrat Republican Other Total
Yes     33.7        0.0   0.0  33.7
No      38.7       13.9  13.7  66.3
```

I would like to reformat the table for it to look like the following:

```
               Democrat      Republican        Other           Total
               Yes   No      Yes   No        Yes   No        Yes   No

Question 1    33.7 38.7     0.0    13.9      0.0  13.7      33.7   66.3
```

The only item that is added is the `Question 1` part, but the rest is simply reformatting. Is this possible, or do I need a new way of creating this table? Btw, it was created using the `prop.wtable` function.

The reason I want to do this is because I have multiple questions that I wish to append to form a larger table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having the structure of your data, it is impossible to be specific. If the object you show is a `matrix` or a `table`, then

```
ftable(tbl.mat, col.vars=2:1)
#  Democrat      Republican      Other      Total     
#       Yes   No        Yes   No   Yes   No   Yes   No
#                                                     
#      33.7 38.7        0.0 13.9   0.0 13.7  33.7 66.3
```

Where `tbl.mat` is the name of the object that you show printed.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you know of a way to format a ftable to latex after? (While keeping the same structure)

Comment: Try `xtable()` in the `xtable` package. Vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Something like below using `reshape`?

```
reshape(
  cbind(as.data.frame(t(dat), row.names = NA), Question = 1, P = colnames(dat)),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Question",
  timevar = "P"
)
```

which gives

```
  Question Yes.Democrat No.Democrat Yes.Republican No.Republican Yes.Other
1        1         33.7        38.7              0          13.9         0
  No.Other Yes.Total No.Total
1     13.7      33.7     66.3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(dat)
structure(c(33.7, 38.7, 0, 13.9, 0, 13.7, 33.7, 66.3), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Yes", "No"), c("Democrat", "Republican",
"Other", "Total")))
```

Comment: No quite what I'm looking for, see above.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for something like what I have shown below.

First, we can loop over each column and get the transpose of each row and the output is a list. Then we can combine the list element column-wise to make a data frame. Finally, we can use `tableHTML` to make the table. An example is given below.

```
library(tableHTML)
ls <- lapply(df, function(x){
  y <- t(x)
  colnames(y) <- rownames(df)
  y
})

comb_df <- do.call(cbind, ls)
rownames(comb_df) <- "Question 1"
tableHTML(comb_df, second_headers = list(c(1,2,2,2,2), c("", names(ls))))
```

---

```
              Democrat      Republican   Other     Total
               Yes  No      Yes No       Yes No    Yes  No
Question 1     33.7 38.7    0   13.9     0  13.7   33.7 66.3
```

---

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Democrat = c(33.7, 38.7), Republican = c(0, 13.9
), Other = c(0, 13.7), Total = c(33.7, 66.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Yes", 
"No"))
```